# Reference to this in anonymous function Dart.js

Tags: dart

Is it possible to get a reference to `this` of creating an object in an anonymous function:

```
var marker = Marker(
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    onTap: () {
       /// <--- here I need a reference to the marker
    });
```

`this` is not working as it is outer object, is it possible to cast something like `this@Marker`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the variable declaration and initialization because the initialization code can't reference the variable it initializes.

If your code is inside a function, you can use

```
Marker marker;
marker = Marker(
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    onTap: () {
       /// <--- here I need a reference to the marker
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot refer to `this` outside of the class itself.
You could try using `marker` to refer to the marker being created, but that will not work here because a variable cannot be referred to inside its own initializer.
So, you have to split the variable declaration from the initialization:

```
Marker marker;
marker = Marker(
    icon: BitmapDescriptor.defaultMarker,
    onTap: () {
      marker.something();
    });
```